# Google calendar (v3) event format

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I've been trying to update a calendar with an event but it doesn't seem to be going through. could you comment on whether I'm formatting my event correctly? I've been struggling with this for some time now.

```
private void InsertEventIntoCalendar()
{
    List<EventAttendee> ef = new List<EventAttendee>();
    ef.Add(new EventAttendee{ Email = "event@gmail.com"});

    List<EventReminder> eventReminder = new List<EventReminder>();
    eventReminder.Add(new EventReminder{ Minutes = 4, Method = "email"});

    Event.RemindersData de = new Event.RemindersData();            
    de.Overrides = eventReminder;

    Event newEvent = new Event
    {
        Attendees = ef,
        Reminders  = de,       
        Summary = "Tin Roof",
        Description = "Its gonna be epic",
        Location = "Claremont",                
        Start = new EventDateTime
        {
            Date = "2012-09-30",
            DateTime = "2012-09-30T10:00:00.000-02:00",
            TimeZone = "Cape Town"

        },
        End = new EventDateTime
        {
            Date = "2012-09-30",
            DateTime = new DateTime(   "2012-09-30T10:25:00.000-02:00",
            TimeZone = "Cape Town"

        },
    };

    _service.Events.Insert(newEvent, "event@gmail.com").Fetch();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it helps anyone else. I figured out how to solve this. I was looking for the answer as well and stumbled on a solution:

```
public static void GCalAdd(string summary, string location, string description,
    DateTime start, DateTime end, List<EventAttendee> attendees)
{
    try
    {
        var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
        {
            ClientIdentifier = ClientCredentials.ClientID,
            ClientSecret = ClientCredentials.ClientSecret
        };

        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthentication);
        var service = new CalendarService(auth);

        var curTimeZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
        var dateOffsetStart = new DateTimeOffset(start, curTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(start));
        var dateOffsetEnd = new DateTimeOffset(end, curTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(end));
        var startTimeString = dateOffsetStart.ToString("o");
        var endTimeString = dateOffsetEnd.ToString("o");

        var evt = new Event
        {
            Summary = summary,
            Location = location,
            Description = description,
            Start = new EventDateTime { DateTime = startTimeString },
            End = new EventDateTime { DateTime = endTimeString },
            Attendees = attendees,
        };

        var insert = service.Events.Insert(evt, "primary").Fetch();

        if (insert != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"calendar item inserted");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}
```

And, to use it, do something like the following:

```
var ea = new EventAttendee
{
    DisplayName = "testname",
    Email = "email@gmail.com",
    Organizer = false,
    Resource = false
};

var ea2 = new EventAttendee
{
    DisplayName = "testname2",
    Email = "email2@gmail.com",
    Organizer = true,
    Resource = false
};

var list = new List<EventAttendee> { ea, ea2 };

var now = DateTime.Now;
var t30 = now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

Program.GCalAdd("test event", "test location", "test description", now, t30, list);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think error in reminder data. Look here - [Google Calendar API v3 with C# - Unable to insert recurrence exceptions.](http://groups.google.com/group/google-calendar-api/msg/15132f45c113eada?dmode=source)